# student attendance table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

my apologies for asking it very uncommon question.

I am using mysql and i have database which has the following tables

```
course
course_subject
subject
student
student_course
department
employee
employee_role
personal_information
attendance
attendance_symbol
```

[image: table structure]

the above database is linked to each other(relational database)... it is fine until when it comes to attendance... when a student enroll to a course it automatically enroll to the subjects that are related to that particular course..

but when it comes to attendance as whole i have some issues which.. but first lets let me tell you folks what i have assumed about attendance which may not be right but that includes:

```
    1. when student enroll to a course it automatically enroll to its subjects
    2. each course has their register students
    3. student enroll on daily basis
```

I cant seems to work it out how cope with the situation... i just need help to create a table that will mark student attendance everyday... once marked dont know may be stored another table or how... need help

and student get it attendance everyday... 
but when it comes to attendance i cant work it out where should i have attendance table... should i link attendance table to student_course or where?

Comment: You can link to images uploaded elsewhere.

Comment: Link to Student Table why you made student_course is one student belong to multiple course if yes then link to student_course table

Comment: @shola as you said link to student_courses.... but cant work out how? how they will be eventually connected to a subjects....

Comment: @flup u can see the image at... http://rawdhatululoom.herobo.com/img/database2.jpg...  and tell me if it is right or wrong thanks for you time once again....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the information of whether a Student attended to a Subject on a certain date, you should have a table like the following:

```
Attendance (student_id, subject_id, date)
```

And then store when the student attended. That way, it will be related to your Student, Subject, but also to student_course as the subject is part of the course. Or you can just store course_id instead of subject_id.

Comment: if you would like to <a href="http://rawdhatululoom.herobo.com/img/database2.jpg"> this design</a> and tell me if it is right or wrong thanks for you time once again....